# how to add table in phpword with laravel

Tags: laravel, phpword, phpoffice

i am trying to draw a table in phpword with laravel
code below is example of writing something in the doc file.

```
        $wordTest = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

    $newSection = $wordTest->addSection();

    $desc1 = "The Portfolio details is a very useful feature of the web page. You can establish your archived details and the works to the entire web community. It was outlined to bring in extra clients, get you selected based on this details.";

    $newSection->addText($desc1, array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 15, 'color' => 'red'));

    $objectWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($wordTest, 'Word2007');

    $objectWriter->save(storage_path('TestWordFile.docx'));
```

please give me an example of how i can draw table there

Comment: try using `addHTML` function and pass full HTML, [reference](https://code-boxx.com/convert-html-to-docx-using-php/)

Comment: but its style doesnt work

Comment: style does't work normally for such file writes cause word doesn't understand CSS. 

try with inline CSS and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

to draw a table i normally use this code

```
$table = array('borderColor'=>'black', 'borderSize'=> 1, 'cellMargin'=>50, 'valign'=>'center');
        $phpWord->addTableStyle('table', $table);
        $table = $section->addTable('table');
        $table->addRow();
        $table->addCell(1750)->addText(htmlspecialchars("#"),$bold);
        $table->addCell(1750)->addText(htmlspecialchars("Attendance Date "),$bold);
```